# Cooliris Jquery pop-up

Tags: jquery, cooliris

im trying to incorporate a cooliris widget to play videos from my youtube channel.. i want a pop-up when someone clicks on the menu option on the link below.. with say a close & minimize button.. googled enough didnt find anything rigid.. im new to jquery..

please help

http://apycom.com/menus/1-black.html

for example.. if someone clicks on say help or products, a pop up must open in jquery with a cooliris widget.. please advice..